# Showing that if $f \in C^k$ and $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),t)$, then $x \in C^{k+1}$ (Proof verification)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, initial-value-problems

I came across the following easy fact (Lemma 3.17) in Meiss' *Differential Dynamical Systems*. Here is my paraphrased version:

> **Lemma.** Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a compact interval, let $f \in C^k(E,\mathbb{R}^d)$ for some $k \geq 0$, and suppose that $x: I \to \mathbb{R}^d$ solves the IVP $$\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t)), \; x(0) = x_0.$$
> Then $x \in C^{k+1}(I,\mathbb{R}^d)$.

I am trying to use this lemma to prove the following analogous claim for nonautonomous IVPs:

> **Claim.** Let $E$ and $I$ be as in the lemma, let $f \in C^k(E \times I, \mathbb{R}^d)$, and suppose that $x: I \to \mathbb{R}^d$ solves the IVP
> \begin{equation}
>     \dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),t), \quad x(0) = x_0. 
> \end{equation}
>
> Then $x \in C^{k+1}(I,\mathbb{R}^d).$

Here is my proof attempt.

*Proof.*  Firstly, we can write $x(t) = (x_1(t),\ldots,x_d(t))$ and $f(x,t) = (f_1(x,t),\ldots,f_d(x,t))$, where $x_i: I \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f_i: \mathbb{R}^d \times I \to \mathbb{R}$ for each $i=1,\ldots,d$. Now define $\tilde{x}: I \to \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ by
\begin{equation}
   \tilde{x}(t) := (x_1(t),\ldots,x_d(t),t) \qquad \forall t \in I. 
\end{equation}

Then for each $i = 1,\ldots,d$, define $\tilde{f}_i: \mathbb{R}^{d+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{equation}
    \tilde{f}_i(s_1,\ldots,s_d,s_{d+1}) := f_i((s_1,\ldots,s_d),s_{d+1}) 
\end{equation}

for all $s = (s_1,\ldots,s_{d+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$.  Now note that
\begin{align*}
   \tilde{f}_i(\tilde{x}(t)) &= \tilde{f}_i(x_1(t),\ldots,x_d(t),t) \\[3pt]
                             &= f_i((x_1(t),\ldots,x_d(t)),t)  \\[3pt]
                             &= f_i(x(t),t). 
\end{align*}

Next, define $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}^{d+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ by
\begin{equation}
   \tilde{f}(s) := (\tilde{f}_1(s),\ldots,\tilde{f}_d(s),1) \qquad \forall s \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}. 
\end{equation}

Clearly, $\tilde{f} \in C^k(\tilde{E},\mathbb{R})$, where $\tilde{E} := E \times I$. Let $x_0 := (x_0^{(1)},\ldots,x_0^{(d)})$ and define $\tilde{x}_0 := (x_0^{(1)},\ldots,x_0^{(d)},0)$. Now observe that $\tilde{x}$ solves the autonomous IVP
\begin{equation}
    \dot{\tilde{x}}(t) = \tilde{f}(\tilde{x}(t)), \quad \tilde{x}(0) = \tilde{x}_0, 
\end{equation}

since
\begin{align*}
   \dot{\tilde{x}}(t) &= (\dot{x}_1(t),\ldots,\dot{x}_d(t),1)  \\[3pt]
                      &= (f_1(x(t),t),\ldots,f_d(x(t),t),1)    \\[3pt]
                      &= (\tilde{f}_1(\tilde{x}(t)),\ldots,\tilde{f}_d(\tilde{x}(t)),1) \\[3pt]
                      &= \tilde{f}(\tilde{x}(t)). 
\end{align*}

It then follows by the lemma that $\tilde{x} \in C^{k+1}(\tilde{E},\mathbb{R})$, which then implies that $x \in C^{k+1}(E,\mathbb{R}). \qquad \square$

My main question is: Is this proof correct? I just want to make sure my reasoning is sound.

---

Update 7/16/23: Thanks to @Filippo for pointing out a much simpler proof:

*Proof*: Fix $k \geq 0$ and let $f \in C^k(E \times I,\mathbb{R}^d)$. We prove that $x \in C^j(I,\mathbb{R}^d)$ for all $j \in \{0,1,\ldots,k+1\}$ by induction on $j$.

Base case $(j = 0)$: By assumption $x$ is differentiable and hence and hence continuous, and so $x \in C^0(I,\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Inductive step: Fix an arbitrary $j \in \{0,1,\ldots,k\}$ and assume $x \in C^j(I,\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then the map $t \mapsto f(x(t))$ is in $C^j(I,\mathbb{R}^d)$ being that it's the composition of the maps $f \in C^j(E \times I,\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $t \mapsto (x(t),t) \in C^j(I,\mathbb{R}^d \times I)$. Hence, $\dot{x} \in C^j(I,\mathbb{R}^d)$ and so $x \in C^{j+1}(I,\mathbb{R}^d)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: @copper.hat: You are right, I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: Doesn't this simply follow from the fact that $\dot x\in C^k$?

Comment: @Filippo: Hmm, but how to justify that $f \in C^k$ implies $f \circ x \in C^k$?

Comment: @Leonidas I think that you can show it by induction: You know that $\dot {x}=f\circ x\in C^1$, hence $x\in C^2$. Hence $\dot {x}=f\circ x\in C^2$, thus $x\in C^3$ and so forth. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Filippo: Ah, you are right! I was over-complicating the proof. Thank you!